# EF Core - Database First Scaffolding creates DTO/aggregate vs entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I normally use code first approach and decided to play around with EF Core 8 and database first approach on an existing working database.

It looks like EF Core creates a collection property in the classes that are scaffolded for every FK relation that the table has. For instance, my "products" table has your typical manufactured product information (i.e., id, name, description, SKU, safety stock level, etc.) and is related by FK to other tables throughout the database (i.e., purhcase order lines, customer order lines, Bill of Materials, etc).

If I were taking a code-first approach, I would create my entity classes, set the DbSet to those classes in DbContext. Code and mapping to/from entitity to DTO from there.

Is it always an effort to let EF Core do its thing when scaffolding database first, and then going through each entity class and removing what isn't needed?

Or, is there a better way using database first to scaffold entity only?
Environment context:

Product Table:
[image: Product Table]

Class created by EF Core:
[image]

Expected Entity Class:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question by fiddling around with EF Core Power Tools extension. This extension allows you to reverse engineer your database and create only POCOs. I'm sure there's a parameter to utilize when using EF to create only POCOs, but I'm not sure what that is. EF Core Power Tools is a bit easier than typing out the DB Scaffold command as it is.